# React function returns the last item in the JSON instead of mapping all of them

Tags: reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet-v3

```
const ZoomToLocation = ({latitude, longitude}) => {
  const map = useMapEvents({
    click() {
    map.setView([latitude, longitude], 15)
    }
  })
  return null
}

function MyMap() {
return(
  <MapContainer>
    {loc.map(loc => (
     <Marker 
     key={loc.properties.id} 
     position={[loc.properties.y, loc.properties.x]}>
       <ZoomToLocation latitude={loc.properties.y} longitude={loc.properties.x}/>
     </Marker>
          ))
     }
  </MapContainer>
)}
```

It maps everything in the `<Marker>` component as I would expect, but doesn't do it in `<ZoomToLocation>`. Instead, it just returns the last item in the JSON.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: what do you get if you `console.log(loc)` within the `loc.map(...)`?

Comment: @Ross I get the correct JSON object. When the map renders all <Marker> components and their props are rendered correctly. I expected that <ZoomToLoction> would behave in the same way as it is rendered within the map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `<ZoomToLocation>`, you could use the `click` event handler of `<Marker>` like this:

```
{loc.map((l) => (
  <Marker
    key={l.properties.id}
    position={[l.properties.y, l.properties.x]}
    eventHandlers={{
      click: (e) => {
        map.flyTo(e.latlng, 15);
      },
    }}
  ></Marker>
))}
```

This will centre the map on the `latlng` property of a marker when you click on it.

You'll need to add the following so you can get a reference to `map`:

```
const [map, setMap] = useState(null);
```

and set the `map` using `whenCreated`:

```
<MapContainer
  ...
  whenCreated={setMap}
>
```

There's a full working demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-leaflet-example-vywznw?file=Map.tsx,index.tsx).